# How do you configure rpm-build on fedora 31 to use xz and NOT zstd?

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I cannot use zstd for rpm-build compression because I need to install the rpm that i build on a centos 8 machine, which does not have zstd supported, and I'm unable to install anything new on that machine with yum. Is there any way for me to configure rpm-build on fedora 31 to use xz compression instead of zstd??

Answer (score 0):

```
dnf install mock
```

And then:

```
mock -r epel-8-x86_64 your-package.src.rpm
```

And you have a package with `xz` payload. And build against RHEL 8 libraries.

This way you can build for any target on any distribution.

Comment: thanks for replying, but when i try to use that, it gives me this error: ERROR: File is not an srpm: mypackage.rpm

Comment: I'm building the rpm from several jars in a java maven project. Is there a way to configure the java maven stuff to use mock?

Comment: foo.src.rpm is the package with sources. foo.rpm contains compiled artifacts. See https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#building-rpms You need to have the foo.src.rpm